# Example of a non-complete isotropic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am looking for an example of a non-complete isotropic manifold. This is because I believe isotropic $\Rightarrow$ homogeneous $\Rightarrow$ complete (with a proof similar to the one in the answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448315/isotropic-manifolds) question). However, as both in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_manifold) and on some online notes, I find the statement "isotropic and complete $\Rightarrow$ homogeneous" I deduce that this is false and that therefore there exists and example as the one of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All isotropic manifolds are complete (and homogeneous, if connected). See

Lemma 8.12.1 in

*Wolf, Joseph A.*, Spaces of constant curvature. 3rd ed, Boston, Mass.: Publish or Perish, Inc. XV, 408 p. $ 10.75 (1974). [ZBL0281.53034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0281.53034).

As Wolf observes, the proof of completeness is the same as for symmetric spaces. It is the same proof as the one sketched by Jason DeVito in a comment to his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448315/isotropic-manifolds).

Comment: @C.F.G: I meant the comment starting with "I guess."

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448315/isotropic-manifolds/448454#comment3966844_448454)?

Comment: Ok thanks! I was pretty sure this was the case, but as I found this written both on my notes and on Wikipedia I had the doubt I was missing something! Clearly I suppose the manifold has to be connected though

Comment: @NicolòCavalleri: Actually, connected is not needed for completeness (one needs this for homogeneity, of course).

Comment: Ok great I am gonna edit the Wikipedia article then