# How can isotropic manifolds be of non-constant curvature?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, curvature, homogeneous-spaces

Wikipedia states that an [isotropic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_manifold) is homogeneous, that is, all points are the same.

But later on, Wikipedia (or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/448337/415941)) states that not all isotropic manifolds are of constant curvature (e.g. $\Bbb{CP}^n$). How can this be? If two points have distinct curvature, how can they be the same?

Comment: The curvature of an isotropic manifold is "constant" in the sense that the Riemann curvature tensors at any two points are equivalent. However, at a given point, the sectional curvatures may not all be the same, so the manifold may have non-constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @Kajelad So, "non-constant curvature" is not meant as varying from point to point, but varying from ... what exactly? It cannot vary with the direction, as the manifold is also isotropic. My intuition seems to be off.

Comment: @M.Winter Sectional curvature is about planes (two dimentional) so if you vary the planes in the tangent bundle which contain some particular vector there is no particular reason that sectional curvatures should be the same(at every point there are multiple sectional curvatures depending on the plane). I am not familiar enough with complex projective spaces to give a full explanation though

Comment: To add to @PaulPlummer's comment, the isotropy group of a point on an isotropic manifold may act transitively on lines, but not necessarily on planes. For instance, in the Fubini Study metric the relevant group action is $U(n)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\cong\mathbb{C}^n$. This action is transitive on $Gr(1,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$, but not on $Gr(2,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$.

Comment: I would totally accept something like this as an answer, if someone would write one!

Comment: @Kajelad Maybe a tiny follow up question. These symmetries seem pretty exceptional to me. Are non-constant curvature isotropic manifolds the rule or the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isotropic manifold $M$ is one for which the isometry group $G$ acts transitively on $M$, and for which the isotropy group $G_p$ acts transitively on spheres in $T_p M$ (for some and hence all $p\in M$).

While the curvature at any two points is "the same" in the sense that we may write the Riemann tensor $R$ as $R(p)=g^*R(q)$ for any $p,q\in M$, this doesn't fully constrain the *sectional* curvature, since different planes in $T_pM$ may have different sectional curvatures. The isotropy condition may not either, since while $G_p$ acts transitively on lines in $T_pM$, it won't necessarily act transitively on planes in $T_pM$.

As an example, consider the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}(n)$ with the Fubini-Study metric. The isometry group is the projective unitary group $G=PU(n+1)=U(n+1)/U(1)$ (since the FS metric is $U(n+1)$ invariant by definition and the center $U(1)$ is the kernel of the action on $\mathbb{CP}(n)$); one can verify this action is transitive. Fixing the line $l=\{(z,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1},z\in\mathbb{C}\}$, one can show that the isotropy group is isomorphic to $U(n)$, and thus the isotropy representation $G_p\to GL(T_pM)$ is just the defining representation of $U(n)$ (though we can forget the complex structure and consider it an action on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$). This representation is transitive on lines, but not on planes for $n\ge 2$. The second claim is evident since the sectional curvature is invariant under this representation, but is not constant on the space of plains $Gr(2,T_pM)$ (en explicit formula is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric#Curvature_properties)).

As for why this is, it seems related to the fact that it is "harder" for the isotropy representation to act transitively on $Gr(2,T_pM)$ than on $Gr(1,T_pM)$, by dimension counting if nothing else. It will if $G_p\cong SO(\dim M,\mathbb{R})$, but in general $G_p$ is only a subgroup of the orthogonal group.

I'm not familiar with the classification of istropic spaces, but it seems that those with constant sectional curvature form only a fraction of the full picture. For instance, if we restrict to the compact, complete, and simply connected case, the only isotropic spaces of constant sectional curvature are round $S^n$, while the other classes $\mathbb{CP}(n)$, $\mathbb{HP}(n)$, and $\mathbb{OP}(2)$ have no constant curvature metrics.

Comment: "and there are still many more to enumerate".  I know we can add $\mathbb{H}P^n$ and $\mathbb{O}P^2$ to the list of non-constant curvature isotropic (closed, 1-connected) manifolds, but are there any others?

Comment: @JasonDeVito "... for sufficiently small values of' 'many' " might be apt. While this is all new to me, [it would appear that those are the only possibilities](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969427).

Comment: Thanks!  So it seems that in odd dimensions, isotropic implies constant curvature, while in even dimensions, you have these other examples.  Weird.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Every isotropic Riemannian manifold is a rank 1 symmetric space (or is flat). This is in Wolf's book on spaces of constant curvature, 8.12.8.  Thus, you have symmetric spaces of rank 1 of negative curvature in addition to your examples, but that's all.